# Does RadRails have keyboard triggers (code templates) as a shortcut for writing repetitive code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts, radrails

One of the things I like about Netbeans Ruby development is [keyboard triggers](http://ruby.netbeans.org/codetemplates-rhtml.html).

For example, **if you are in an erb template** and you **type**:

```
licai
```

After you hit the **tab key**, this text gets **replaced with**:

```
<%= link_to "${1 default="link text..."}", 
:controller => "${2 default="items"}", 
:action => "${3 default="edit"}", 
:id => ${4 default="@item"} %>
```

And then you can use the tab key to fill out each of the arguments.

I'm evaluating RadRails and I really miss this feature from Netbeans.

**Is there anything similar in RadRails?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, look under Window | Preferences and then Ruby -> Editor -> Templates to see the existing list of code templates that have been defined or to add your own.

Then the keyboard shortcut you want is <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> e.g. type "render" and press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to see the list of render templates.